# AsyncTask to get text file and transfer lines to strings

Tags: android, android-asynctask, void, protected

How would you get a text file off the internet to download and update pre-determined string names so that the files could be used on a TextView and so the application wouldn't have to be updated when information had to be changed. I have already setup a AsyncTask so the file can be downloaded in the background but how would I get the file downloaded, read and then put into strings and then to have a TextView reloaded so the text could be updated. Any help or code on this would be greatly appreciated and I already have the

protected void doInBackground part setup and ready. I have been having trouble with this for some time so any help could be very handy. I have tried using httppost to get the file but I did not understand what I had to change so it worked. Thanks for reading!

The text file in question is http://nowactivity.webs.com/teststring.txt

Comment: You will have to paste some code, but have in mind that you will probably have to use jsoup for this in the `AsyncTask`.

Comment: @g00dy do you have any quick way I could do this? I have no knowledge of jsoup.

Comment: I have, but I'll have to dig a little bit for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a more complete answer:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

...

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    // perform Long time consuming operation
Document doc = null;
String returnValue ="";
String baseWebPage = "http://nowactivity.webs.com/teststring.txt";

for(int i = 0; i< params.length; i++){
  try {
    doc = Jsoup.connect(
        baseWebPage)
        .get();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
  }

  Log.i("DOC", "The line " + doc.toString());

}

  return returnValue;
}
```

I'm sure you can mange the rest of your implementation ;-)

More about jsoup can be found [here](http://jsoup.org/).

Cheers

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH! You have been a godsend!

Comment: Can I ask what did you use for your AsyncTask Params, Progress and result?

Comment: Yes, I used the `params` to pass the final part of the URL to the `AsyncTask` and thus to request different pages to be parsed, based on that final part. About the progress, if you of course mean `onProgressUpdate()` - I don't use that. And if by result you mean the return value of the `doInBackground`, I use it to return the last part of the webpage address or some other String, depending of some `if`{}`else`{} statements and nothing more. :)